# Installing mysql-operator on kubernetes is failing

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

So I am following the guide (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-operator/en/mysql-operator-installation-kubectl.html) to install MySql cluster on a Kubernetes Ubuntu Server 22.04 cluster.

I have run the following commands successfully to import the required yaml deployment files

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/trunk/deploy/deploy-crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/trunk/deploy/deploy-operator.yaml
```

Now when I then run the deployment command, the pod keeps restarting.

```
kubectl get deployment mysql-operator --namespace mysql-operator
```

Here is the output of the logs (I receive an error)

```
kubectl logs mysql-operator-755b988dd9-jn7f6 --namespace=mysql-operator
exec /usr/bin/mysqlsh: exec format error
```

And here is the describe:

```
 kubectl describe pod mysql-operator-755b988dd9-jn7f6 --namespace=mysql-operator
Name:             mysql-operator-755b988dd9-jn7f6
Namespace:        mysql-operator
Priority:         0
Service Account:  mysql-operator-sa
Node:             mnetk8s-node-a1/10.30.0.11
Start Time:       Wed, 07 Jun 2023 22:52:40 +0100
Labels:           name=mysql-operator
                  pod-template-hash=755b988dd9
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.3.6
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.3.6
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mysql-operator-755b988dd9
Containers:
  mysql-operator:
    Container ID:  docker://785da7db660ae71ad09e1d6ecf7672f68fbbfbf1e03b64b4619bde188c7a250f
    Image:         container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/community-operator:8.0.33-2.0.10
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/community-operator@sha256:9c411c679b416b7d4bce4e14f65b311105429d25c3183f864fdd9baec8d5647f
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      mysqlsh
      --log-level=@INFO
      --pym
      mysqloperator
      operator
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 07 Jun 2023 23:34:29 +0100
      Finished:     Wed, 07 Jun 2023 23:34:29 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  13
    Readiness:      exec [cat /tmp/mysql-operator-ready] delay=1s timeout=1s period=3s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MYSQLSH_USER_CONFIG_HOME:                 /mysqlsh
      MYSQLSH_CREDENTIAL_STORE_SAVE_PASSWORDS:  never
    Mounts:
      /mysqlsh from mysqlsh-home (rw)
      /tmp from tmpdir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-jdn2d (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mysqlsh-home:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  tmpdir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-jdn2d:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  46m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned mysql-operator/mysql-operator-755b988dd9-jn7f6 to mnetk8s-node-a1
  Normal   Pulled     45m (x5 over 46m)    kubelet            Container image "container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/community-operator:8.0.33-2.0.10" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    45m (x5 over 46m)    kubelet            Created container mysql-operator
  Normal   Started    45m (x5 over 46m)    kubelet            Started container mysql-operator
  Warning  BackOff    97s (x221 over 46m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container mysql-operator in pod mysql-operator-755b988dd9-jn7f6_mysql-operator(9e7f8c17-4fdd-4f98-a074-d2112019b28e)
```

Any help or ideas would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec format error` usually means the image you are using are not for the architecture you are deploying on. That is, you are using an ARM image on a AMD64 node or vice versa.

Since all of the MySQL images on oracle container registry are AMD64 images, my guess is that your cluster is running on an ARM arch, like an Ampere instance.

You're going to need to run on an x64 arch instance, or find an image for ARM, or go to the source and rebuild the image for ARM.

Comment: I am using Arm so that makes sense. OK I'll see what I can find that isn't amd64. Thank you!

Comment: if you are using Oracle Cloud, I'd strongly suggest you use OKE. Basic OKE clusters cost only for compute/storage usage with no additional overhead, and it's all managed for you. Much easier than running your own cluster.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this out.

An open-source tool called [kubeblocks](https://github.com/apecloud/kubeblocks) for deploying and managing MySQL on Kubernetes.

I think it can solve your problem.